# How to create custom ToggleSwitch Style in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, toggleswitch

I am trying to create a custom to ToggleSwitch Style for a UWP app by going into the Document Outline for the Toggle Switch and selecting Edit a Copy and place in my style resource dictionary.  However, when I do this I get an XAML Error, *XDG0062: The Resource "Unknown" has an incompatible type*.  This is before I even make any changes to the style, just when I create the copy and set the ToggleSwitch to the new style.  The error actually manifests in the Grid holding the toggle button.

To Replicate:  Create a new page, add a grid, add a ToggleSwicth.  In then Document outline, Edit the template with a copy an place into a resource dictionary.  Note: same issue with a slider control too.

I 'feel' the issue is with the Header and/or On/Off content presenters, because the default content 'disappears' when pointing the control to the new style, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> To Replicate: Create a new page, add a grid, add a ToggleSwicth. In then Document outline, Edit the template with a copy an place into a resource dictionary. Note: same issue with a slider control too.

Yep, I can reproduce your issue, it looks Visual Studio Xaml designer's problem. After build the solution, the xaml error will dismiss automatically. So please build your solution after add the template copy. And you could also try to update your  Visual Studio to [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#xaml-tools-wpf-uwp--xamarinforms).

And you could also close it manually.

```
Tools->Options->Xaml->Miscellaneous-> Uncheck Show error detected by the xaml designer.
```

Comment: OK and thanks.  I did some more testing on a clean project and my original, also updated Visual Studio to latest.  For me the error never goes away.  It will build, but the error is always there.  Another issue is that when using the copied template, the Header, OnContent and OffContent will not show in the designer.  They seem to show fine in the running app, just not the designer.  I am reluctant to turn off XAML errors as I am new to XAML and I need the 'help'.

Comment: Fine, Please feel free report the issue in Visual Studio Send Feed Back.

Comment: VS Feedback provided.

Comment: Great, Thanks for your feedback.